# Product of four consecutive integers cannot equal the product of two

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[Question 5](http://www.bmoc.maths.org/home/bmolot.pdf#page=39)

> Prove that the product of four consecutive positive integers cannot be
>   equal to the product of two consecutive positive integers.

So it must equal $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ hence it must be divisible by 24 (In the sequence there must be a factor of 4,2,3. This must equal to $k(k+1)$. As $k$ and $k+1$ are co prime either $k$ or $k+1$ is divisible by 24, or one is divisible by 8 and the other by 3.

I run out of ideas since nothing pops out to me and the factorisations don't seem reveling. I also recognised the two formulae as 2*triangular numbers and 24*sum of the sum of triangular numbers, both appearing in pascals triangle. But thats more of a interesting observation then something useful in a proof.

I would appreciate a pointer how to proceed.

Comment: Maybe try that $4k(k+1)+1$ is a perfect square?

Answer (score 6):

$$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) = (n^2 + 3n)(n^2 + 3n +2)$$

If $n^2 + 3n \geq k$, then $(n^2 + 3n)(n^2 + 3n +2) > k(k+1)$

If $n^2 + 3n <k$, then $(n^2 + 3n)(n^2 + 3n +2) < k(k+1)$

Answer (score 3):

$$(n^2+3n)(n^2+3n+1)\lt n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)\lt(n^2+3n+1)(n^2+3n+2)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $m$ be the smallest of the four positive consecutive integers, and $n$ be the smallest of the two consecutive integers. Then we have:
$$m(m + 1)(m + 2)(m + 3) = n(n + 1).$$
Since
\begin{align*} m(m + 1)(m + 2)(m + 3) &= [m(m + 3)][(m + 1)(m + 2)] \\ &= (m ^ 2 + 3m)(m ^ 2 + 3m + 2)  \\&= [(m ^ 2 + 3m + 1) - 1][(m ^ 2 + 3m + 1) + 1] \\ &= (m ^ 2 + 3m + 1) ^ 2 - 1,\end{align*}
the original equation becomes:

$$(m ^ 2 + 3m + 1) ^ 2 - 1 = n(n + 1) \iff (m ^ 2 + 3m + 1) ^ 2 = n ^ 2 + n + 1.$$
However, as $$n ^ 2 < n ^ 2 + n + 1 < n ^ 2 + 2n + 1 = (n + 1) ^ 2,$$
the above equation suggests that exclusively between two consecutive perfect squares $n ^ 2$ and $(n + 1) ^ 2$, there is another perfect square $(m ^ 2 + 3m + 1) ^ 2$, which can never be true, given that $m$ and $n$ are positive integers.

Therefore, the product of four consecutive positive integers cannot be equal to the product of two consecutive positive integers, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

No number of the form $m(m+1)$ where $m$ is a positive integer (the sequence $t_m = 2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42,\dots$) can also be of the form $m(m+2)$ (the sequence $u_m = 3, 8, 15, 24, 35, 48,\dots$) because the sequences are both increasing and terms of each sequence are sandwiched between consecutive terms of the other sequence. It's easy to see $t_m < u_m < t_{m+1}$ since $m(m+1) < m(m+2) < (m+1)(m+2)$. The other answers boil down to showing that numbers of the form $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ are all of the form $m(m+2)$. The underlying strategy is to rewrite the quartic expression $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ to look more like the quadratic $k(k+1)$, find a quadratic sequence that it is a subsequence of, and then show these two quadratic sequences don't share any values. (Proving two sequences share no values is much easier when you have two sequences growing at similar rates, rather than one quadratic and one quartic.)

But the question can also be solved another way: possible values of $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$, clearly get spread very far apart, so what values of $k$ could make $k(k+1)$ even get *close* to one? Intuitively we need $k \approx n^2$. But this is too small:

$$k(k+1)=n^2(n^2+1) = n^4 + n^2 < n^4 + 6n^3 + 11n^2 + 6n = n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$$

We need to get the $6n^3$ term somehow. Considering

$$(n^2 + pn)^2 = n^4 + 2pn^3 + p^2n^2 \approx n^4 + 6n^3$$

suggests taking $p=3$ and trying $k=n^2 + 3n$. But this is *still* too small:

$$k(k+1)=(n^2+3n)(n^2+3n+1) = n^4 + 6n^3 + 10n^2 + 3n < n^4 + 6n^3 + 11n^2 + 6n$$

We're only too small by $n^2 + 3n$ so we must be nearly there. The next possible value of $k$ is $k=n^2+3n+1$. Try it and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

An interesting factoid (which is implicitly contained in the earlier answers) makes it easy to understand why those answers are correct: The product of four consecutive integers is always $1$ less than a perfect square; viz $$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)=a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)$$
where $a=n^2+3n+1$

Since the product of four consecutive integers is the product of two integers that differ by $2$, it is readily apparent it cannot be the product of two integers that differ by $1$